# dlv hugo just hangs

Tags: go, hugo, delve

I am trying to learn Hugo using a Go debugger called `dlv`. And I am pretty stuck. After:

```
go get -v github.com/gohugoio/hugo
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo
go  build -gcflags="-N -l"
dlv exec ./hugo -- -s /path/to/the/projectdir
```

This hangs. Pressing Ctrl+C runs `hugo` as normal. As far as I can see `dlv debug` not only produces the same behavior but it's the exact same: the produced binary called `debug` is the exact same as the `hugo` I built with `go  build -gcflags="-N -l"`.

dlv launches a number of child processes, these disappear after a while. The `hugo` process is visible via `ps` and `pidof hugo` but `strace -p`pidof hugo`` reports `strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): No such proce`. Checking after, it's still in the ps list, the same pid. I would guess because it's in `t` state as it is being traced.

How could I then watch Hugo running?

Comment: Because I want to learn and become a developer of hugo (maybe). Best way to learn a new framework is to step through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, doesn't happen for me. dlv prompt appears right away. I am on fedora, have been using hugo regularly over the past week or so.

```
$ dlv exec ./hugo -- --cleanDestinationDir -s /path/to/blog/root/
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) c

                   | EN  
+------------------+----+
  Pages            | 25  
  Paginator pages  |  0  
  Non-page files   |  0  
  Static files     | 11  
  Processed images |  0  
  Aliases          |  0  
  Sitemaps         |  1  
  Cleaned          |  0  

Total in 46 ms
Process 41032 has exited with status 0
$
```

Answer (score 4):

Aaaaand it's Linux subsystem for Windows! I never thought that'd make a difference but following Jonah B's answer " I am on fedora" I tried it on a Debian box and it worked. I am surprised because strace works fine on WSL (actually the github instructions on filing a report includes strace). I filed this [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2977).

Comment: Great report. I have not heard of many of these kinds of regressions on WSL, great to learn of this.

Answer (score 0):

Same experience here. However it doesn't hang, it just takes a significant time to reach the dlv prompt.

Check the usage of your memory (for instance with mpstat or vmstat if you are on Linux). I have 16G main mem and 16G of swap. Until the dlv prompt is reached, nearly all my memory and a significant amount of swap is consumed. During the startup time any playing video or music stutters and the PC is practically unusable until dlv is ready.

Hugo is pretty large app in that respect.

Comment: This is not what I see. This is not what strace shows either: dlv spawns six processes, I went over them with strace -p, half of them are not doing anything, half of them are in a futex wait loop.